# URL validation using regular Expression vue JS

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, url

I am trying to validate URL strings with a regular expression. I am using this regex to validate URLs:

```
var regex = /^(http|https):\/\/+[\www\d]+\.[\w]+(\/[\w\d]+)?/
```

Using this I am able to parse almost all kinds of URL except `http://www.google` this kind of URL. I want that this URL falls into false case.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with that kind of url? Should it not start with `www.`?

Comment: if it start with www then it should not allow www.google but must allow http://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to make multiple changes to make it work:

- There is no need to add `+` quantifiers in `\/\/`.
- No need to add `\w` in `[w\d]+`. Since you are matching `www` or `w3` something like this so `\w` is allowed means you are allowing alphanumeric and underscore also.
- Add `$` at the end of the regex, match only if it matches completely

```js
var regex = /^(http|https):\/\/[w\d]+\.[\w](\/[\w\d]+)?$/;
const str = "http://www.google";

console.log(regex.test(str));
```

Comment: This is not working for me. When I copy and paste this into JS Fiddle, changing the str to ["http://www.google.com"](http://www.google.com) also returns "false".